# Erro de chamadas recursivas em procedures aninhadas

Tags: mysql, recursão, stored-procedures

Tenho algumas *procedures* MySQL para fazer o seguinte:

- O código principal vai sempre chamar a procedure `CALL sp_syncTabela`.
- A `sp_syncTabela` vai checar se existe outra procedure específica para o `tableName` passado como argumento. Se existir, será chamada; se não, a procedure "padrão" `sp_syncExecuteQuery` será chamada no lugar.
- Por exemplo, eu tenho a `sp_syncTabela_caixa` na database. Então, quando eu executo `CALL sp_syncTabela (..."caixa"...)`, ela vai internamente chamar `CALL sp_syncTabela_caixa`. Mas uma chamada a `CALL sp_syncTabela (..."outra"...)` vai apenas usar a procedure padrão `sp_syncExecuteQuery`.
- Todas as procedures específicas têm o formato `sp_syncTabela_???`, como a "caixa" possui. Essas procedures servem para executar outras tarefas personalizadas além de chamar `CALL sp_syncExecuteQuery`.
- A lógica é: A tabela referenciada pelo argumento `tableName` possui uma procedure específica? Se tiver, faça algumas tarefas personalizadas à tabela e depois chame `sp_syncExecuteQuery`; mas se não tiver, apenas execute `sp_syncExecuteQuery` sem nenhuma tarefa extra.

Eu não vejo nenhuma chamada recursiva, mas estou recebendo o erro

> Error Code: 1444. The prepared statement contains a stored routine
>   call that refers to that same statement. It's not allowed to execute a
>   prepared statement in such a recursive manner.

Isso está acontecendo depois de executar `CALL sp_syncTabela ("I", 33, "caixa",   "id='20',fundo='11.11',abertura_user_id='2',abertura_data='2014-11-11 18:24:33',fechamento_user_id=NULL,fechamento_data=NULL,", "id=20")`.

Agora, os códigos:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_syncTabela`(IN action VARCHAR(10), IN tableName VARCHAR(50), IN columnData VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN
    DECLARE res Int;

    SELECT Count(*) INTO res FROM information_schema.Routines WHERE routine_name = Concat("sp_syncTabela_", tableName);

    CASE res
        WHEN 0 THEN CALL sp_syncExecuteQuery (action, tableName, columnData);
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET @querySync = Concat("CALL sp_syncTabela_", tableName, " (\"", action, "\", \"", tableName, "\", \"", columnData, "\");");
            PREPARE tablePreviewQuery FROM @querySync;
            EXECUTE tablePreviewQuery;  
        END;
    END CASE;
END


CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_syncTabela_caixa`(IN action VARCHAR(10), IN tableName VARCHAR(50), IN columnData VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN
    /* Apenas uma procedure específica de exemplo, com uma tarefa adicional antes de chamar sp_syncExecuteQuery */

    INSERT INTO configuration (name, value) VALUES ("Última chamada à sp_syncTabela_caixa", Cast(Now() as Char)) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = Cast(Now() as Char);
    CALL sp_syncExecuteQuery (action, tableName, columnData);

END


CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_syncExecuteQuery`(IN action VARCHAR(10), IN tableName VARCHAR(50), IN columnData VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN

    CASE action
        WHEN "I" then CALL sp_generateInsertQuery (tableName, columnData, @queryToExecute);
        WHEN "U" then CALL sp_generateUpdateQuery (tableName, columnData, @queryToExecute);
        WHEN "D" then CALL sp_generateDeleteQuery (tableName, columnData, @queryToExecute);
        ELSE Begin End;
    END CASE;

    PREPARE tablePreviewQuery FROM @queryToExecute;
    EXECUTE tablePreviewQuery;  
END
```

Já procurei ajuda em vários sites, em português e inglês, por palavras-chave como 'nested procedures', 'recursive errors', e similares. E, além de tudo, não vejo onde há recursividade nesse processo. Quando executo diretamente a `sp_syncTabela_caixa`, não ocorre nenhum erro.

Comment: Ulisses, você declarou que a sp_syncTabela receberá 3 parametros, e depois fez a chamada da sp passando 5 parametros CALL sp_syncTabela ("I", 33, "caixa",   "id='20',fundo='11.11',abertura_user_id='2',abertura_data='2014-11-11 18:24:33',fechamento_user_id=NULL,fechamento_data=NULL,", "id=20"). Pelo que você criou ali na sp só pode passar 3 parametros action VARCHAR(10), IN tableName VARCHAR(50), IN columnData VARCHAR(4000)

Comment: o erro que apareceu aqui no meu teste foi Error Code: 1318. Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE local.sp_syncTabela; expected 3, got 5 0.000 sec

Comment: Ola, tem um exemplo de chamada recursiva[nesse hilo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando executar uma consulta preparada que chama `sp_syncTabela_` com os mesmos parâmetros, o que leva a uma chamada recursiva.

Para resolver esse problema, você deve evitar a chamada recursiva em `sp_syncTabela`. Se você precisa executar a mesma lógica em diferentes situações, considere separar a lógica em uma função ou procedimento diferente que possa ser chamado sem causar recursão.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_syncTabela`(IN action VARCHAR(10), IN tableName VARCHAR(50), IN columnData VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN
    DECLARE res Int;

    -- Verifica se a rotina específica para a tabela já existe
    SELECT Count(*) INTO res FROM information_schema.Routines WHERE routine_name = Concat("sp_syncTabela_", tableName);

    IF res = 0 THEN
        -- A rotina não existe, chame a lógica desejada diretamente
        CALL sp_syncExecuteQuery(action, tableName, columnData);
    ELSE
        -- A rotina existe, execute-a diretamente
        SET @querySync = Concat("CALL sp_syncTabela_", tableName, " (\"", action, "\", \"", tableName, "\", \"", columnData, "\");");
        PREPARE tablePreviewQuery FROM @querySync;
        EXECUTE tablePreviewQuery;
    END IF;
END;
```

Nesta versão corrigida, primeiro verificamos se a rotina específica para a tabela já existe no banco de dados. Se não existir, chamamos `sp_syncExecuteQuery` diretamente. Se existir, executamos a rotina existente diretamente, sem fazer uma chamada recursiva para `sp_syncTabela`.

Answer (score 0):

O erro "Error Code: 1444. The prepared statement contains a stored routine call that refers to that same statement. It's not allowed to execute a prepared statement in such a recursive manner." ocorre quando uma stored procedure é chamada dentro de um comando PREPARE que foi criado por outra stored procedure. Isso é considerado uma chamada recursiva e é proibido pelo MySQL.

Para evitar esse erro, você pode mudar a lógica da sua stored procedure sp_syncTabela para não utilizar PREPARE e EXECUTE. Em vez disso, você pode utilizar uma declaração SELECT para selecionar o nome da stored procedure específica que você deseja chamar e, em seguida, chamar essa stored procedure usando a função EXECUTE.

Aqui está um exemplo de como isso poderia ser feito:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_syncTabela`(IN action VARCHAR(10), IN tableName VARCHAR(50), IN columnData VARCHAR(4000))
BEGIN
    DECLARE res INT;
    DECLARE procName VARCHAR(100);

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO res FROM information_schema.Routines WHERE routine_name = CONCAT("sp_syncTabela_", tableName);

    CASE res
        WHEN 0 THEN
            EXECUTE CONCAT('CALL sp_syncExecuteQuery (', action, ', ', tableName, ', ', columnData, ')');
        ELSE 
            SELECT CONCAT("sp_syncTabela_", tableName) INTO procName;
            EXECUTE CONCAT(procName, ' (', action, ', ', tableName, ', ', columnData, ')');
    END CASE;
END
```

Dessa forma, a stored procedure sp_syncTabela não estará mais chamando outra stored procedure dentro de um comando PREPARE, e o erro de chamada recursiva não deverá ocorrer mais.

Answer (score -1):

Olá.
No seu código, na procedure `sp_syncExecuteQuery`, tem a variável `@queryToExecute`, ela aparece tanto no CASE, quanto no PREPARE, qual o conteúdo dela?
Ao final do código da `sp_syncExecuteQuery` você tem:

```
PREPARE tablePreviewQuery FROM @queryToExecute;
EXECUTE tablePreviewQuery;
```

O `EXECUTE tablePreviewQuery;` pelo visto irá executar o que tem em `@queryToExecute`, portanto é importante saber o que esta variável contém, a recursividade pode estar aí.